# Как подключить SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку. Пытаюсь установить Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Открываю Management Studio и когда в настройках нажимаю connect появляется такая ошибка. Не устанавливается соединение и пишет проблема с сервером[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: откройте порты [Настройка брандмауэра Windows - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: экземпляр БД запущен(через "Агент SQL Server" делается)?